# Getting Time range between non intersecting ranges

Tags: kotlin

I have the following timelines :

```
7 a.m --------------------- 12 a.m.  2 am .................. 10 a.m
         10-------11                        3------5
            closed                          closed
```

```
the output should be the non-intersecting time ranges:
 7-10 a.m, 11 -12 a.m, 2-3 p.m, 5-10 p.m
```

I tried to minus and subtract method for Ranges but didn't work
A tricky part could be the following case

```
7 a.m --------------------- 12 a.m.  2 am .................. 10 a.m
          10----------------------------------------5
                              closed
```

```
the output should be the non-intersecting time ranges:
 7-10 a.m, 5-10 p.m
```

Any Idea for kotlin implementation?

I tried to minus and subtract method for Ranges but didn't work

Comment: So the input is a list of ranges representing opening times, and a list of ranges representing closing times, and you want to find out exactly when it is open?

Comment: @Sweeper that's right

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a pretty common case and I suspect there are some existing algorithms for it, but nothing comes out of top of my head.

My idea is to first transform both lists of ranges into a single list of opening/closing "events", ordered by time. The start of an opening range increases the "openess" by `+1` while its end decreases it (`-1`). Start of a closing range also decreases "openess" while its end increases it. Then we iterate the events in the time order, keeping the information on what is the current "openess" level. Whenever the "openess" level is `1`, that means we are in the middle of an opening range, but not inside a closing range, so we are entirely open.

Assuming both lists of ranges are initially properly ordered, as in your example, I believe it should be doable in linear time and even without this intermediary list of events. However, such implementation would be pretty complicated to cover all possible states, so I decided to go with a simpler solution which is I believe `O(n * log(n))`. Also, this implementation requires that opening ranges do not overlap with each other, the same for closing ranges:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    // your first example
    println(listOf(Range(7, 12), Range(14, 22)) - listOf(Range(10, 11), Range(15, 17)))
    // second example
    println(listOf(Range(7, 12), Range(14, 22)) - listOf(Range(10, 17)))

    // two close rangs "touch" each other
    println(listOf(Range(8, 16)) - listOf(Range(10, 11), Range(11, 13)))
    // both open and close range starts at the same time
    println(listOf(Range(8, 16)) - listOf(Range(8, 12)))
}

data class Range(val start: Int, val end: Int)

operator fun List<Range>.minus(other: List<Range>): List<Range> {
    // key is the time, value is the change of "openess" at this time
    val events = sortedMapOf<Int, Int>()
    forEach { (start, end) ->
        events.merge(start, 1, Int::plus)
        events.merge(end, -1, Int::plus)
    }
    other.forEach { (start, end) ->
        events.merge(start, -1, Int::plus)
        events.merge(end, 1, Int::plus)
    }

    val result = mutableListOf<Range>()
    var currOpeness = 0
    var currStart = 0
    for ((time, change) in events) {
        // we were open and now closing
        if (currOpeness == 1 && change < 0) {
            result += Range(currStart, time)
        }
        currOpeness += change
        // we were closed and now opening
        if (currOpeness == 1 && change > 0) {
            currStart = time
        }
    }

    return result
}
```